# Indexers Invalid, Constant Errors from Crontab

Tags: cron, magento-2.2.1

I use a shared hosting service and installed Magento 2.2.1 through a one-click installer in my host's control panel. After installation, I immediately saw the error: `One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.`

In an attempt to repair this error, I created cronjobs in the Cronjobs Settings of my hosting control panel, using the three commands listed in the documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html *(edited for privacy)*

```
* * * * * | /usr/local/php7/bin/php /home/www/WEBSITE.com/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/www/WEBSITE.com/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * | /usr/local/php7/bin/php /home/www/WEBSITE.com/update/cron.php >> /home/www/WEBSITE.com/var/log/update.cron.log  
* * * * * | /usr/local/php7/bin/php /home/www/WEBSITE.com/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/www/WEBSITE.com/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Not long thereafter, I started being inundating with emails of the following error:

```
Cron: '/usr/local/php7/bin/php /home/www/WEBSITE.com/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/www/WEBSITE.com/var/log/magento.cron.log'

[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'DB_NAME' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1226] User 'DB_NAME' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 20)
cron:run [--group GROUP] [--bootstrap BOOTSTRAP]
```

To fix this error, I contacted the hosting provider's tech support, who then told me that `max_user_connections` is hard-coded on shared plans at 20 and it could not be altered.

This led me to go back through the documentation listed above and follow the steps in the Prerequisites, but as I do not have root access to the server, (since I'm on a shared hosting plan) I can not run commands like

```
crontab -u magento_user -e
```

So at this point I'm just lost. I'm unsure of what to do to make this work. I am still new to site administration and Magento so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error you described that is **`One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.`**

Go to you **Magento** root category & fire this command from your magento root directory

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

& for setting the cron error just fire these three commands into your **`terminal/cmd`** from your **Magento** root directory

> php bin/magento cron:run
>
> php update/cron.php
>
> php bin/magento setup:cron:run

If still facing any issue feel free to do revert back

Comment: When I run either command, I get this error: `Deprecated: Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/www/WEBSITE.com/bin/magento on line 21`.

Comment: You need to upgrade your php version from 5.3 to 7 so it will not show that error & then perform the above commands

Comment: I have already had it set to PHP 7 for a while now. Checked again just now and confirmed that's what it's at.

Comment: Now it is showing what, the same error?

Comment: Yes, I didn't make any change. It was set to PHP 7 to begin with.

Comment: run phpinfo() in your server to see that it is really working on php7 or not.

Make sure it should not be Php 7.1 because magento didn't supports php 7.1

Comment: I did have the server running 7.1 at some point, but when I realized that 7.1 is unsupported, I reverted back to PHP 7. I have run the command and verified that the server is running 7, although I did have to prefix the php command with the location of the php7 file. Now that I know to prefix php, I have rerun the commands above and they all worked. The indexers have been fixed, thank you. But I still am getting the errors in my email. Any clue what to do there given my situation?

Comment: just delete the update.log file from var/log & rerun the above cron related all three command & check whether the update.log is still get generated?

Revert back what error it is showing in update.log file & check all other logs also to trace the errors

Comment: If my answer helped you do vote & accept it so that it can help others also facing the same issue